# Stored procedure: if no record exists run different select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In my stored procedure, I have the following statement:

```
SELECT TOP 200 
    C.CustomerNumber,
    C.CustomerName,
    C.AccountManager,
    C.CustomerId        
FROM 
    Customer C WITH(NOLOCK, index (UQ_Customer_CustomerNumber))
LEFT JOIN 
    CustomerQuotingPreference cp WITH(NOLOCK) ON cp.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE  
    (C.CustomerName LIKE ('%' +  @searchString + '%') 
    OR C.CustomerNumber LIKE ('%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(61), @searchString) + '%')))
ORDER BY
    C.CustomerName
```

I want to check now that if this select returns no records, run a different select.

Comment: Have a look at `@@ROWCOUNT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Usually I put this kind of logic in application code.

Comment: NOLOCK makes sense with certain edge cases...but I doubt this is one of them, especially if you want clean data!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Temp Table
(
    CustomerNumber VarChar, //or whatever type these are
    CustomerName   VarChar,
    AccountManager VarChar,
    CustomerId     Int
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT TOP 200  
    C.CustomerNumber,
    C.CustomerName,
    C.AccountManager,
    C.CustomerId        
FROM 
    Customer C WITH(NOLOCK, index (UQ_Customer_CustomerNumber))
LEFT JOIN 
    CustomerQuotingPreference cp WITH(NOLOCK) ON cp.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE  
    (C.CustomerName LIKE ('%' +  @searchString + '%') 
    OR C.CustomerNumber LIKE ('%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(61), @searchString) + '%')))
ORDER BY
    C.CustomerName

IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM @Temp
        RETURN
    END

SELECT * FROM OtherTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this way

```
if exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM 
        Customer C WITH(NOLOCK, index (UQ_Customer_CustomerNumber))
    LEFT JOIN 
        CustomerQuotingPreference cp WITH(NOLOCK) ON cp.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
    WHERE  
        (C.CustomerName LIKE ('%' +  @searchString + '%') 
        OR C.CustomerNumber LIKE ('%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(61), @searchString) + '%')))
)

SELECT TOP 200  
    C.CustomerNumber,
    C.CustomerName,
    C.AccountManager,
    C.CustomerId        
FROM 
    Customer C WITH(NOLOCK, index (UQ_Customer_CustomerNumber))
LEFT JOIN 
    CustomerQuotingPreference cp WITH(NOLOCK) ON cp.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE  
    (C.CustomerName LIKE ('%' +  @searchString + '%') 
    OR C.CustomerNumber LIKE ('%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(61), @searchString) + '%')))
ORDER BY
    C.CustomerName;
else
    SELECT * FROM OtherTable;
```